# Communication between Python Keras CNN Model and C# Backend Project

Tags: python, c#, keras, service

I have prer-trained python model at local jupyter notebook and C# backend which is working on Visual Studio. I have input picture and I have to send Python model and evaluate after I have to take back for prediction result to C# backend. How can I do this communications on simplest way? I am thinking on service comminication between them, is there a possible solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that I did for a project that had a similar structure, was to run the python model in Django framework locally and make the C# backend to communicate with the model through a Django service. Django will run as a local web service.
This was a good pattern in my idea as it would isolate the python model and I was able to alter it separately from the C# backend. The python model could become available as a web service for other projects that need the same functionality.
I've heard C# is able to run python code within the code, so you can use that too.

Comment: I done with socket connection using UDP. Which is give me best speed of comminication. Also, you suggestion true for web service, anyone can do with djago, flash or web api ...

Answer (score 0):

I use python script to evaluate input on pre-trained neural networks writing XML file that contain output values and save it on Google drive.

Later, I download XML file to process it using Console application using C#.

Comment: You write true too but your solution is little bit tricky. You don't have to connect to Google Drive from inside C#. Just run python script into C# and save output values in project and paste anywhere. These solution more helpful I think. Question time was too old, however answers will help to anyone :)